# PowerShell IntelliSense targeting older versions of PowerShell

Tags: powershell, intellisense

Newer versions of the PowerShell ISE (and third-party PowerShell scripting environments like PowerGUI) offer pretty good IntelliSense support.

However, I often write scripts that I want to run on servers which only have older versions of PowerShell installed (in particular, PowerShell 2.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2). I can't upgrade the PowerShell installation on the server and the PowerShell 2.0 ISE doesn't have IntelliSense.

Is there any way to configure the PowerShell 3.0 or 4.0 ISE, or PowerGUI (or any other free PowerShell script editor!) to provide IntelliSense which is restricted to PowerShell 2.0 compatible code only?

Comment: If you have a remote computer with 2.0 installed, but not 3.0, then I think (but have not tested) that if you open a remote tab to that 2.0 machine, your Intellisense will work against 2.0 - but just in the remote tab.

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed Jason's theory that Intellisense does work in PSRemoting against the installed version of Powershell, but it looks a bit different. I tested using Powershell preview build 5.0.10018.0 remoting to Server 2008R2 with PS v2.0. I ran:

```
$Procs = Get-Process
$Procs <Ctrl + Space>
```

This resulted in an Intellisense tooltip with options like:

```
$Procs.count
$Procs.Clear(
```

Where v3.0 and up would only include the property or method names, not the variable itself.

I also tested for the .Where() and .Foreach() magic methods which did not show up in Intellisense. This seems to confirm that it's working against the installed version.